# ByteArray writeByte(0x0)

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, byte

I was wondering what the `0x0` in `byteArray.writeByte(0x0)` means?

Is it writing a `null` value into the byte array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x0` is actually zero, not `null`. It's [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) notation. The decimal equivalent would be `0`, so you could just as well write `byteArray.writeByte(0)`.